# How do I screenshot my Electron application of a Scratch project?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, screenshot, mit-scratch

I essentially used turbo_warp packager to make an Electron windows application of a [Scratch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_%28programming_language%29) project and I'd like to know how we can press a button to screenshot the application window to make it a separate image so I can easily save it to my hard disk drive.

Basically, the Scratch project is a random image generator and I'd like to screenshot the image whenever I press a button, so the screenshotted image will appear (either below the application or a pop-up window or anything really). I tried to use html2canvas and Electron's desktop capture. How can I get it working?

P.S.: This is the Scratch project: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/127701037/

#### File *Main.JS*

```javascript
'use strict';
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, shell, screen} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const isWindows = process.platform === 'win32';
const isMac = process.platform === 'darwin';
const isLinux = process.platform === 'linux';

if (isMac) {
  // TODO
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { role: 'appMenu' },
    { role: 'fileMenu' },
    { role: 'editMenu' },
    { role: 'viewMenu' },
    { role: 'windowMenu' },
    { role: 'help' }
  ]));
} else {
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);
}

const isSafeOpenExternal = (url) => {
  try {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(url);
    return parsedUrl.protocol === 'https:' || parsedUrl.protocol === 'http:';
  } catch (e) {
    // ignore
  }
  return false;
};

const createWindow = () => {
  const options = {
    width: 250,
    height: 225,
    useContentSize: true,
    minWidth: 50,
    minHeight: 50,
    icon: path.resolve('icon.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      sandbox: true
    },
    show: false,
    backgroundColor: "#000000"
  };

  const activeScreen = screen.getDisplayNearestPoint(screen.getCursorScreenPoint());
  const bounds = activeScreen.workArea;
  options.x = bounds.x + ((bounds.width - options.width) / 2);
  options.y = bounds.y + ((bounds.height - options.height) / 2);

  const window = new BrowserWindow(options);
  window.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    window.show();
  });
  window.loadFile('../../index.html');
};

const acquiredLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (acquiredLock) {
  app.enableSandbox();

  app.on('web-contents-created', (event, contents) => {
    contents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
      if (isSafeOpenExternal(details.url)) {
        setImmediate(() => {
          shell.openExternal(details.url);
        });
      }
      return {action: 'deny'};
    });
    contents.on('will-navigate', (e, url) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (isSafeOpenExternal(url)) {
        shell.openExternal(url);
      }
    });
  });

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit();
  });

  app.on('second-instance', () => {
    createWindow();
  });

  app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
    app.on('activate', () => {
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
    });
  });
} else {
  app.quit();
}
```

#### File *index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created with https://packager.turbowarp.org/ -->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <!-- We only include this to explicitly loosen the CSP of various packager environments. It does not provide any security. -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:">
  <title>Map Maker Final</title>
  <style>
    body {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    :root, body.is-fullscreen {
      background-color: #000000;
    }
    [hidden] {
      display: none !important;
    }
    h1 {
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #app, #loading, #error, #launch {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .screen {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: default;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      background-color: #000000;
    }
    #launch {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .green-flag {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      padding: 16px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      border: 3px solid hsla(0, 100%, 100%, 1);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #loading {

    }
    .progress-bar-outer {
      border: 1px solid currentColor;
      height: 10px;
      width: 200px;
      max-width: 200px;
    }
    .progress-bar-inner {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      background-color: currentColor;
    }
    .loading-text {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin: 0 0 16px;
    }
    .loading-image {
      margin: 0 0 16px;
    }
    #error-message, #error-stack {
      font-family: monospace;
      max-width: 600px;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      user-select: text;
      -webkit-user-select: text;
    }
    #error-stack {
      text-align: left;
      max-height: 200px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .control-button {
      width: 2rem;
      height: 2rem;
      padding: 0.375rem;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      margin-top: 0.5rem;
      margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .control-button:hover {
      background: #ff4c4c26;
    }
    .control-button.active {
      background: #ff4c4c59;
    }
    .fullscreen-button {
      background: white !important;
    }
    .standalone-fullscreen-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
      padding: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .sc-canvas {
      cursor: auto;
    }

  </style>
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <!-- no favicon -->
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>Enable JavaScript</noscript>

  <div id="app"></div>

  <div id="launch" class="screen" hidden title="Click to start">
    <div class="green-flag">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 16.63 17.5" width="42" height="44">
        <defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-2{fill:#4cbf56;stroke:#45993d;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}.cls-2{stroke-width:1.5px;}</style></defs>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M.75,2A6.44,6.44,0,0,1,8.44,2h0a6.44,6.44,0,0,0,7.69,0V12.4a6.44,6.44,0,0,1-7.69,0h0a6.44,6.44,0,0,0-7.69,0"/>
        <line class="cls-2" x1="0.75" y1="16.75" x2="0.75" y2="0.75"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="loading" class="screen">


    <div class="progress-bar-outer"><div class="progress-bar-inner" id="loading-inner"></div></div>
  </div>

  <div id="error" class="screen" hidden>
    <h1>Error</h1>
    <details>
      <summary id="error-message"></summary>
      <p id="error-stack"></p>
    </details>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    const appElement = document.getElementById('app');
    const launchScreen = document.getElementById('launch');
    const loadingScreen = document.getElementById('loading');
    const loadingInner = document.getElementById('loading-inner');
    const errorScreen = document.getElementById('error');
    const errorScreenMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
    const errorScreenStack = document.getElementById('error-stack');

    const handleError = (error) => {
      console.error(error);
      if (!errorScreen.hidden) return;
      errorScreen.hidden = false;
      errorScreenMessage.textContent = '' + error;
      let debug = error && error.stack || 'no stack';
      debug += '\nUser agent: ' + navigator.userAgent;
      errorScreenStack.textContent = debug;
    };
    const setProgress = (progress) => {
      if (loadingInner) loadingInner.style.width = progress * 100 + '%';
    };

    try {
      const scaffolding = new Scaffolding.Scaffolding();
      scaffolding.width = 250;
      scaffolding.height = 225;
      scaffolding.resizeToFill = false;
      scaffolding.setup();
      scaffolding.appendTo(appElement);

      // Expose values expected by third-party plugins
      window.scaffolding = scaffolding;
      window.vm = scaffolding.vm;

      const {storage, vm} = scaffolding;
      storage.addWebStore(
        [storage.AssetType.ImageVector, storage.AssetType.ImageBitmap, storage.AssetType.Sound],
        (asset) => new URL('./assets/' + asset.assetId + '.' + asset.dataFormat, location).href
      );
      storage.onprogress = (total, loaded) => {
        setProgress(0.2 + (loaded / total) * 0.8);
      };
      setProgress(0.1);

      scaffolding.setUsername("Smartplus50".replace(/#/g, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)));
      scaffolding.setAccentColor("#ff4c4c");

      scaffolding.addCloudProvider(new Scaffolding.Cloud.WebSocketProvider("wss://clouddata.turbowarp.org", "586286535"));

      if (false) {
        const greenFlagButton = document.createElement('img');
        greenFlagButton.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16.63 17.5"><path d="M.75 2a6.44 6.44 0 017.69 0h0a6.44 6.44 0 007.69 0v10.4a6.44 6.44 0 01-7.69 0h0a6.44 6.44 0 00-7.69 0" fill="#4cbf56" stroke="#45993d" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/><path stroke-width="1.5" fill="#4cbf56" stroke="#45993d" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M.75 16.75v-16"/></svg>');
        greenFlagButton.className = 'control-button';
        greenFlagButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          scaffolding.greenFlag();
        });
        scaffolding.addEventListener('PROJECT_RUN_START', () => {
          greenFlagButton.classList.add('active');
        });
        scaffolding.addEventListener('PROJECT_RUN_STOP', () => {
          greenFlagButton.classList.remove('active');
        });
        scaffolding.addControlButton({
          element: greenFlagButton,
          where: 'top-left'
        });
      }

      if (false) {
        const stopAllButton = document.createElement('img');
        stopAllButton.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 14"><path fill="#ec5959" stroke="#b84848" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M4.3.5h5.4l3.8 3.8v5.4l-3.8 3.8H4.3L.5 9.7V4.3z"/></svg>');
        stopAllButton.className = 'control-button';
        stopAllButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          scaffolding.stopAll();
        });
        scaffolding.addControlButton({
          element: stopAllButton,
          where: 'top-left'
        });
      }

      if (false && (document.fullscreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled)) {
        let isFullScreen = !!(document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement);
        const fullscreenButton = document.createElement('img');
        fullscreenButton.className = 'control-button fullscreen-button';
        fullscreenButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          if (isFullScreen) {
            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
              document.exitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
              document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            }
          } else {
            if (document.body.requestFullscreen) {
              document.body.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
              document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            }
          }
        });
        const otherControlsExist = false;
        const fillColor = otherControlsExist ? '#575E75' : '#ffffff';
        const updateFullScreen = () => {
          isFullScreen = !!(document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement);
          document.body.classList.toggle('is-fullscreen', isFullScreen);
          if (isFullScreen) {
            fullscreenButton.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent('<svg width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="' + fillColor + '" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M12.662 3.65l.89.891 3.133-2.374a.815.815 0 011.15.165.819.819 0 010 .986L15.467 6.46l.867.871c.25.25.072.664-.269.664L12.388 8A.397.397 0 0112 7.611V3.92c0-.341.418-.514.662-.27M7.338 16.35l-.89-.89-3.133 2.374a.817.817 0 01-1.15-.166.819.819 0 010-.985l2.37-3.143-.87-.871a.387.387 0 01.27-.664L7.612 12a.397.397 0 01.388.389v3.692a.387.387 0 01-.662.27M7.338 3.65l-.89.891-3.133-2.374a.815.815 0 00-1.15.165.819.819 0 000 .986l2.37 3.142-.87.871a.387.387 0 00.27.664L7.612 8A.397.397 0 008 7.611V3.92a.387.387 0 00-.662-.27M12.662 16.35l.89-.89 3.133 2.374a.817.817 0 001.15-.166.819.819 0 000-.985l-2.368-3.143.867-.871a.387.387 0 00-.269-.664L12.388 12a.397.397 0 00-.388.389v3.692c0 .342.418.514.662.27"/></g></svg>');
          } else {
            fullscreenButton.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent('<svg width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="' + fillColor + '" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M16.338 7.35l-.89-.891-3.133 2.374a.815.815 0 01-1.15-.165.819.819 0 010-.986l2.368-3.142-.867-.871a.387.387 0 01.269-.664L16.612 3a.397.397 0 01.388.389V7.08a.387.387 0 01-.662.27M3.662 12.65l.89.89 3.133-2.374a.817.817 0 011.15.166.819.819 0 010 .985l-2.37 3.143.87.871c.248.25.071.664-.27.664L3.388 17A.397.397 0 013 16.611V12.92c0-.342.418-.514.662-.27M3.662 7.35l.89-.891 3.133 2.374a.815.815 0 001.15-.165.819.819 0 000-.986L6.465 4.54l.87-.871a.387.387 0 00-.27-.664L3.388 3A.397.397 0 003 3.389V7.08c0 .341.418.514.662.27M16.338 12.65l-.89.89-3.133-2.374a.817.817 0 00-1.15.166.819.819 0 000 .985l2.368 3.143-.867.871a.387.387 0 00.269.664l3.677.005a.397.397 0 00.388-.389V12.92a.387.387 0 00-.662-.27"/></g></svg>');
          }
        };
        updateFullScreen();
        document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', updateFullScreen);
        document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', updateFullScreen);
        if (otherControlsExist) {
          fullscreenButton.className = 'control-button fullscreen-button';
          scaffolding.addControlButton({
            element: fullscreenButton,
            where: 'top-right'
          });
        } else {
          fullscreenButton.className = 'standalone-fullscreen-button';
          document.body.appendChild(fullscreenButton);
        }
      }

      vm.setTurboMode(true);
      if (vm.setInterpolation) vm.setInterpolation(true);
      if (vm.setFramerate) vm.setFramerate(60);
      if (vm.renderer.setUseHighQualityRender) vm.renderer.setUseHighQualityRender(false);
      if (vm.setRuntimeOptions) vm.setRuntimeOptions({
        fencing: false,
        miscLimits: false,
        maxClones: 9999999999,
      });
      if (vm.setCompilerOptions) vm.setCompilerOptions({
        enabled: true,
        warpTimer: true
      });

      if (typeof ScaffoldingAddons !== 'undefined') {
        ScaffoldingAddons.run(scaffolding, {"gamepad":false,"pointerlock":false,"specialCloudBehaviors":false});
      }

      for (const extension of []) {
        vm.extensionManager.loadExtensionURL(extension);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      handleError(e);
    }

    // NW.js hook
    if (typeof nw !== 'undefined') {
      const win = nw.Window.get();
      win.on('new-win-policy', (frame, url, policy) => {
        policy.ignore();
        nw.Shell.openExternal(url);
      });
      win.on('navigation', (frame, url, policy) => {
        policy.ignore();
        nw.Shell.openExternal(url);
      });
      document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Escape' && document.fullscreenElement) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        }
      });
    }

    // Electron hook
    if (true) {
      document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'F11') {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (document.fullscreenElement) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
          } else {
            document.body.requestFullscreen();
          }
        }
      });
    }


  </script>
  <script>
    const getProjectData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = () => {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = () => {
        if (location.protocol === 'file:') {
          reject(new Error('Zip environment must be used from a website, not from a file URL.'));
        } else {
          reject(new Error('Request to load project data failed.'));
        }
      };
      xhr.onprogress = (e) => {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          setProgress(0.1 + (e.loaded / e.total) * 0.1);
        }
      };
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      xhr.open("GET", "./assets/project.json");
      xhr.send();
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    const run = async () => {
      const projectData = await getProjectData();
      await scaffolding.loadProject(projectData);
      setProgress(1);
      loadingScreen.hidden = true;
      if (true) {
        scaffolding.start();
      } else {
        launchScreen.hidden = false;
        launchScreen.addEventListener('click', () => {
          launchScreen.hidden = true;
          scaffolding.start();
        });
        launchScreen.focus();
      }
    };
    run().catch(handleError);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the Scratch project rendered on a canvas element? If so, then you could try [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob).

Comment: No, I don't think it uses canvas element, but just in case, I'll post the scratch project here. I just want a method where I can easily create a seperate screenshot of the image generator for it to easily save it to a specific folder with a right-click or with a press of a button etc.

Comment: I'm asking because I know both the [Scratch website](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/127701037/) and the [TurboWarp website](https://turbowarp.org/127701037) use canvas to render a project (you can tell by right-clicking the stage and selecting 'inspect'). I have no experience with Electron, so I cannot judge that, but I am expecting something _very_ similar.